# how to compare value between selected range and column in Vba

Tags: vba, excel

I wrote this script. It copies selected columns by user to another tab and also prints them after last row. I want to develop it. when it wants to copy cells to another tab found matched values with destination column and rewrite it.so it avoids duplicated values. I am new to Vba, please help me :) much appreciated.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim Result As Excel.Worksheet
    Set Result = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Result")

    Dim rColumn As Range, rRow As Range

    X = Sheets("Result").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'Used range in A approx.

    For Each rRow In Selection.Rows

        For Each rColumn In Selection.Columns

            Result.Cells(X + 1, rColumn.Column).Value = Cells(rRow.Row, rColumn.Column).Value

        Next

        X = X + 1
    Next

End Sub

Function hasColumn(Target As Range, vColumn As Variant)
    hasColumn = Not Intersect(Target, Target.Parent.Columns(vColumn)) Is Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: what is the difference between `copies` and `prints` ?

Comment: copy means it copies values and print them to specific column in another tab. maybe same, I just changed the word. @jsotola

Comment: i thought that maybe you wanted to convert numeric values to strings when you said print. please use consistent language in your questions

Comment: @jsotola sorry for misunderstanding , yes sure try my best next time :) can you help me ??

Comment: Can you include images of your data and desired output?

Comment: Is your Function hasColumn related to the problem? It doesn't appear to be so you might be able to remove this.

Comment: @QHarr Yes sure I do that now, and you are right function there is useless, it is for previous try and I forgot to delete it. Thanks

Comment: By duplicate do you mean an entire row appearing more than once in Result sheet? A particular cell value appearing more than once? Any value appearing more than once?  Or do you mean something else completely.